# msWFSGetFeature(): WFS server error. FLTApplyFilterToLayer() failed

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, wfs, ogr

I have the following code that generates a map with a couple of layers.

```
var PIDS = ["NSW502756064","NSW500951450","NSW500951433","NSW500951487","NSW500951527","NSW500951536","NSW502756058","NSW502756059","NSW513255000",
"NSW513255001","NSW513255009","NSW500952157","NSW500952183","NSW500952156","NSW500952181","NSW513254999","NSW500952182","NSW500952060","NSW513255018",
"NSW513255016","NSW513255017","NSW513255019","NSW500952081","NSW500952059","NSW500952078","NSW500952080","NSW513246310","NSW513246342","NSW500952139",
"NSW500952140","NSW515573633","NSW500952118","NSW515832904","NSW500951694","NSW500951946","NSW512878142","NSW512878163","NSW500951677","NSW500951562",
"NSW502756060","NSW515833545","NSW500951817","NSW500951996","NSW502756128","NSW515576212","NSW500951994","NSW500952216","NSW500952229","NSW500952239",
"NSW500952175","NSW500952229","NSW500952233","NSW500951537","NSW500951466","NSW515570881","NSW500951697","NSW502756089","NSW500951728","NSW500951697",
"NSW500951698","NSW500951642","NSW502756228","NSW500951426","NSW515570894"];

var filtered = filterResults(PIDS);

function init() {

    var streets = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Query Layer",
        "http://xxxx:8081/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.0.0&map=../../council.map",
        {
            layers: 'NSW_STREET',
            queryVisible: true, 
            visibility: false,
            isBaseLayer: false, 
            transparent: true, 
            format: 'image/gif',
            numZoomLevels: 22
        }
    );

    var council = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            url:  "http://xxxx:8081/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&map=../../council.map", 
            featureType: "NSW_STREET",
            geometryName: "Geometry", 
            transparent: true,
            visible: false,
            opacity: 0.5,
            renderers: renderer
        }),
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(style),
        filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
        filters: filtered       
        })
    });

   council.setVisibility(true);

    var roads = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("ROADS", 
       "http://xxxx:8081/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.0.0&map=../../council.map",
       { 
           layers: "state,locality",
           numZoomLevels: 22        
         });

    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
            numZoomLevels: 22,
            controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition()
            ]
        });     

    map.addLayers([roads, streets, council]);       

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(148.17447, -33.13967).transform( // Bogan Street
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4283"),
        map.getProjectionObject()
    ), 15);
}


var template = {
    strokeWidth: 3 
};

var style = new OpenLayers.Style(template);

var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;

function filterResults(thePids) {
    var filterlist = [];
    for (i=0;i<thePids.length;i++) {
        filterlist.push(new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                                type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                                property: "STREET_LINE_PID",
                                value: thePids[i]
                            })
                     )
    }
    return filterlist;
}
```

I want the council layer to be filtered based on the road segments (PIDS) contained in the PIDS array. The problem I am having at the moment is that if the PIDS array holds fewer than 65 elements it'll render correctly.

[image]

However once I increase the number of elements in this array beyond 65 then nothing renders and the log file reveals the following error:

```
getSymbol(): Symbol definition error. Parsing error near (WHERE):(line 149)
[Wed Oct 10 13:31:12 2012].591000 msOGRFileWhichShapes(): OGR error. SetAttributeFilter( ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW502756064')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951450')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951433')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951487')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951527')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951536')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW502756058')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW502756059')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW513255000')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW513255001')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW513255009')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952157')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952183')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952156')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952181')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW513254999')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952182')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952060')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW513255018')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW513255016')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW513255017')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW513255019')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952081')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952059')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952078')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952080')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW513246310')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW513246342')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952139')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952140')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW515573633')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952118')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW515832904')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951694')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951946')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW512878142')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW512878163')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951677')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951562')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW502756060')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW515833545')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951817')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951996')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW502756128')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW515576212')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500951994')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952216')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952229')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID= 'NSW500952239')  Or  ( (STREET_LINE_PID=
[Wed Oct 10 13:31:12 2012].592000 msWFSGetFeature(): WFS server error. FLTApplyFilterToLayer() failed
```

Your help in figuring out what's going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that is may be a bug with the latest stable release of mapserver. Compiled the latest beta version and now it works.